# Xamarin Forms - StackLayout inside AbsoluteLayout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, absolutelayout

I'm new to Xamarin Forms and I'm stuck trying to make StackLayout work inside an AbsoluteLayout. There are 2 children inside my StackLayout: an Image (300x300 random image) and a Label. I'll show an example that illustrates my problem.

The following code works just fine for me (i'm using a 300x300 image) :

```
public class TestedPage : ContentPage
{
    public TestPage()
    {
    BackgroundColor = Color.Brown;
    StackLayout stl = new StackLayout();
    AbsoluteLayout ab = new AbsoluteLayout();

    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("circle.png");

    Label lbl = new Label
    {
        Text = "#Text1000",
        TextColor = Color.White,
        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)),
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    };

    stl.Children.Add(img);
    stl.Children.Add(lbl);

    ab.Children.Add(stl);

    Content = ab;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the above code simply will throw '*stl*' in it without positioning, which is big deal for me because I need it to be positioned exactly where I want.
So, you may ask "why don't you use more parameters for Children.Add() ?", well `ab.Children.Add(stl, new Rectangle(0,0,450,450));` will not position '*stl*' correctly, for me at least, in the above code, it will be at start of screen and a bit after center, to the right, and not origin(0,0).
Also, curious that I debugged and found out that Stack, Image and Absolute all have different height and width. Above code gives me 450, 450 for '*stl*' (which is fine); 616, 360 for '*ab*'; 150, 450 for '*img*'.

So, is there anything I'm missing here ? It is a little confusing for me because I get it to work but it's a little "buggy", does not behave as I expected. 
Since I'm not experienced in Xamarin Forms I believe I'm missing something important here, which is why I hope you guys might give me some clues.

Any ideas ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(stl, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(stl, new Rectangle(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, but I forgot to mention two things : using AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All won't help me in this situation as it is a little specific. All the code we have done so far is using Flags set to None, and when I set it to All, elements start to behave incorrectly: they get wrong random positions as well as sometimes not showing up (images/labels) will simply disappear.
Last one is that I'm already using SetLayoutBounds to position children, it's just that it's not consistent.